# Items should be arrange into three columns in CheckedListBox or listview or listbox

Tags: vb.net, winforms, listview, listbox, checkedlistbox

I have used `CheckedListBox` control in vb.net application.

I have several items as follow, item 1, item 2, item 3........item 100.

Now, i want all these items to arrange into three columns and then appear verticle scrollbar.

But, in `CheckedListBox`, it appears as horizontally. i want it to appear horizontally for just three columns and then vertical scroll should enable.

Can you please suggest if possible in `CheckedListBox` control or any other control and if possible then how i would have to set its property to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do that in a CheckedListBox....

You could create a `FlowLayoutPanel`, with a fixed width and add `AutoScroll = True`.
Then add a number of `CheckBox` controls to it.

[image]

You could have problems regarding column alignment and margins. If that's the case, you can set the checkbox Autosize = False and make them a little larger (in order to contain the text)

[image]

Or you can reduce the Height of the checkboxes to reduce spaces (is this what you want?)

eg. `Height = 15`

[image]

Comment: How to remove spaces into flowlayout control as it shows extra spaces between the controls.

Comment: @Dhaval I don't know what you're talking about. Margins maybe? check the edit

Comment: this would mean creating more than 100 checkboxes for me, and is not vaiable

Answer (score 0):

Use repeat direction =horizontal and repeat column =3 for checkbox list

Comment: I could not find RepeatDirection and RepeatColumn property into CheckedListBox control (winform application).

Comment: what control are you talking about? and who voted this up...?